# Alembic: IntegrityError: "column contains null values" when adding non-nullable column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm adding a column to an existing table. This new column is `nullable=False`.

```
op.add_column('mytable', sa.Column('mycolumn', sa.String(), nullable=False))
```

When I run the migration, it complains:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: column "mycolumn" contains null values
```

Answer (score 136):

It is because your existing data have no value on that new column, i.e. `null`. Thus causing said error. When adding a non-nullable column, you must decide what value to give to already-existing data

---

**Alright, existing data should just have "lorem ipsum" for this new column then. But how do I do it? I can't UPDATE because the column is not there yet.**

Use the [`server_default`](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.alter_column.params.server_default) arg:

```
op.add_column('mytable', sa.Column(
    'mycolumn', 
    sa.String(), 
    nullable=False, 
    server_default='lorem ipsum', #  <---  add this
))
```

---

**But, but, I don't want it to have default value**

Drop it afterwards using `op.alter_column('mytable', 'mycolumn', server_default=None)`

E.g. your `upgrade()` function would be:

```
def upgrade():
    op.add_column('mytable', sa.Column('mycolumn', sa.String(), nullable=False, server_default='lorem ipsum'))
    op.alter_column('mytable', 'mycolumn', server_default=None)
```

Comment: @Steve use `'True'` and `'False'` instead of `True` and `False`

Comment: It is also important to note that all values should be passed as string (even for integers!) since server_default is specifically the SQL text that one would specify in the "DEFAULT" section of a "CREATE TABLE" statement. 

In my case, I had to specify `op.add_column(
        "project",
        sa.Column("tenant_id", sa.Integer(), nullable=False, server_default="1"),
    )` to make it work (my id are integer)

Comment: In case of default values for `bool` type use `sa.sql.expression.false()` or `sa.sql.expression.true()` as follows: `op.add_column('table', sa.Column('col_name', sa.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default=sa.sql.expression.false()))`

Comment: To add to this answer if you also want to add a column that's unique you can do it with these two lines: `op.execute("UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = 'lorem ipsum-' || id")`   `op.create_unique_constraint('mycolumn_key', 'mytable', ['mycolumn'])` and drop it with `op.drop_constraint('mycolumn_key', 'mytable', type_='unique')`

Answer (score 48):

An alternative to @Ron's answer is to do the contrary, and modify the data **before** adding the constraint:

```
def upgrade():
    op.add_column('my_table', sa.Column('my_column', sa.String()))
    op.execute('UPDATE my_table SET my_column=my_other_column')
    op.alter_column('my_table', 'my_column', nullable=False)
```

Seems cleaner and more powerful to me, but you're writing SQL :-).

Comment: when using MySQL backend, last line should be op.alter_column('my_table', 'my_column', existing_type=sa.String(), nullable=False), otherwise you'll get an alembic.util.exc.CommandError (more about that [here](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.alter_column))

Comment: Isn't this kinda dependant on the size of the table you're running the UPDATE on? Imagine a production table with 1M records... :/

Comment: @Arjunsingh's answer does the same with SQLAlchemy objects rather than SQL.

Answer (score 24):

It tells you - rightly - that there are (or will be) existing NULL values in the database for that column. The answer is to edit the migration file to update the column before changing the column definition:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column

def upgrade():
    op.add_column('role', sa.Column('role_name', sa.String(length=30), nullable=True))
    role = table('role', column('role_name'))       
    op.execute(role.update().values(role_name=''))       
    op.alter_column('role', 'role_name', nullable=False)
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner way to do it vs. the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Reflecting on Ron's comment, If you're using the class inheriting db.Model, you can add this (`server_default` parameter) to the model itself without changing the migration script. Specifically, the `is_deleted` and `created_at` columns are using it:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)

    is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, server_default=false(), nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), default=datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc), server_default=db.func.now(), nullable=False)

    @classmethod
    def query(cls):
        return super(User, cls).query.filter_by(is_deleted=False)
```